# Is it possible to inject values from the KO view model to a template?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Would like to understand whether it's possible to inject values from the view model in to a template with out using "data-bind" using Knockout JS.

For example, if I have the following view model;

```
var myViewModel = {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable("ABC");
    self.lastName = ko.observable("XYZ");
};
```

I need to create a template like the following;

```
<script id="myInjectTemplate" type="text/html">
    <h3 id="header_${firstName}">${firstName} - ${lastName}</h3>
</script>
```

Where I could just inject the values in the view model to the place holders, just like we do in Apache Velocity ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to use data-bind?

Comment: You need to go down the way of using mustache for this: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/

Comment: @PaulManzotti : My view model contains meta data for a DB schema. What I'm trying to do is to create a UI to reflect the schema. While doing that, I need to name certain DOM elements according to a naming convention which contains parts of the meta data I have in my view model. Hope this explains the scenario I'm trying to tackle. Tx.

Comment: @OmegaSilva Ah, given that, you need to ask a different question! See my answer for what I think you should have been asking. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the id using data binding too, you know, so you can do both:

```
<h3 data-bind="attr: { id: 'header_$' + firstName() }, text: firstName() + ' - ' + lastName()"></h3>
```

Though I'd look at using a computed observable to create a full name from the first and last name observables.

Comment: Thanks Paul! This is exactly what I was looking for. Apologies for not including what I really needed in my original question.

Comment: Ha, no worries! Unless you know how to do something, it's often very hard to know what you should be asking. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to go down the way of using mustache for this: github.com/janl/mustache.js

```
    var view = {
       title: "Joe",
       calc: function () {
           return 2 + 4;
       }
    };

var output = Mustache.render("{{title}} spends {{calc}}", view);
```

Comment: Thanks XGreen. Didn't know about Mustache until now. Will try this out.